# Pull author data from closed file

Tags: excel, vba

How could I pull a file’s Author and Last author given two conditions: (1) without opening the file, (2) can get any file’s data.

I found code using “BuiltinDocumentProperties(“Author”)” and “BuiltinDocumentProperties(“Last author”)”. The file needs be opened (see https://exceloffthegrid.com/reading-document-properties-vba/). Some files are big and this may take a while.

Comment: Pretty sure the workbook has to be open to access those properties.

Comment: If the files are saved as `xlsx` or `xlsm` (not `xls` or `xlsb`) that info is contained in the XML in `docProps\core.xml`.  You may be able to extract that info.  [heres one example that might help](https://jkp-ads.com/Articles/Excel2007FileFormat02.asp)

Answer (score -4):

Maybe this.

http://learnexcelmacro.com/wp/2011/11/how-to-get-list-of-all-files-in-a-folder-and-sub-folders/

I'm not sure you can get the details of the file's author.  Maybe you can do it.  Google it!!